# Rotating the image to get it an upright position

Tags: r, image, matrix, transpose

I am trying to visualise an image of a number `5`. Initially with code:

```
image(matrix(data[,11552], nrow = 28, byrow = TRUE), col = gray(0:255/255))
```

it looks like the following image:
[image]

When I take a transpose of the matrix using the code:

```
image(t(matrix(data[,11552], nrow = 28, byrow = TRUE)), col = gray(0:255/255))
```

, it looks like:

[image]

As you could see, I still cannot get an upright `5`. How could I rotate the image further so that I get `5` in an upright position?

The dimension of `data` is given as :

```
[1]   784 11552
```

Comment: What is `dim(data)`?

Comment: @G5W `[1]   784 11552`

Comment: *'take a transpose of the matrix using the code"* is showing code identical ... I'm assuming you're just using `t(...)`, is that correct?

Comment: @r2evans Yes,  corrected the code in question.

Comment: Looks like a similar question was asked this week

Comment: @akrun Could you share the link?

Comment: I don't remember the link.  Probably Julius answered it

Comment: My guess is that your origin (bottom-left) is different from the origin of the source data (which might be upper-left). For plotting, you should be able to use `image(...,ylim=1:0)` to reverse the y-axis; you might be able to y-flip your data with `m <- data[,11552]; m <- m[,ncol(m):1]`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is the following what you are asking for?

```
windows()
image(volcano)

windows()
image(volcano[nrow(volcano):1, ncol(volcano):1])
```

Note: I am running this on Windows.

**EDIT.**

The code above flips the image both horizontally and vertically. If all what is needed is to display the image upside down, just reverse the columns index.

```
windows()
image(volcano[, ncol(volcano):1])
```

Comment: Yeah, the same effect

Comment: Could you build on that? I did not understand.

Comment: Rotating the second image by 90deg will give an upright `5`

Comment: @Jatt See if the edit does it. And if not, I suggest you play with indices reversal a bit.

Answer (score 0):

You could try reversing the data (with `rev()`) instead of transposing it?

Just a thought, as `t()` flips horizontal and vertical, so that `t(t(data))` = `data`.

Comment: This throws an error `argument must be matrix-like`